# Reading int's in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, int

I've been studying Haskell, more specifically the `IO` monad, and I would like to know how can i do the following:

Let's say I have this function signature:

```
getNumber :: String −> (Int −> Bool) −> IO Int
```

and this text:

"My name is Gary, and I'm 21 years old"

If I want to read only the number "21" from this sentence, how would I do it in Haskell ?

Comment: What is the `Int->Bool` for?

Comment: `getNumber` is apparently an interactive function (ask for numbers until once comes that satisfies the predicate)? Otherwise, it shouldn't have this `IO` signature. BTW the name isn't great in that case, better actually call it `askForNumber`. — At any rate, this function certainly can't seem a tool that could be used for extracting something from a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that extracts multiple readable things from a `String`:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr, tails)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

readMany :: Read a => String -> [a]
readMany = unfoldr $ listToMaybe . concatMap reads . tails
```

So for example:

```
> readMany "I like the numbers 7, 11, and 42." :: [Int]
[7,11,42]
```

You can easily specialize this to jozefg's function `getNumber`:

```
justOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
justOne [x] = Just x
justOne _   = Nothing

getNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
getNumber = justOne . readMany
```

Or you can be a little more lenient and pick the first number when more than one is specified:

```
getNumber = listToMaybe . readMany
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with list processing operations,

```
import Text.Read
import Data.Char

getNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
getNumber = readMaybe . takeWhile isDigit . dropWhile (not . isDigit)
```

Now it's much easier to use this to build your function. It's not clear what the `Int -> Bool` is for, or, if you already have the string, why you need `IO`. To get your function you could do something like

```
yourFunc :: (Int -> Bool) -> IO Int
yourFunc f = do
   r <- fmap getNumber getLine
   case r of
     Nothing -> putStrLn "Please enter a number" >> yourFunc f
     Just x | f x       -> return x
            | otherwise -> putStrLn "Doesn't satisfy predicate" >> yourFunc f
```

Usage:

```
> yourFunc even
  I am a person
  Please enter a number
  I am 21
  Doesn't satisfy predicate
  I am 22
  22
```

However if you want to do any serious parsing, I'd recommend Parsec or Attoparsec, they're both quite easy to use and much more robust.

Comment: But this function signature is  different from the one i wrote isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but It's trivial to use this to build your signature. @dcarou

Comment: `takeWhile` can be omitted using `reads` - `fmap fst . headMay . reads . dropWhile (not . isDigit)` (or `fst . head . reads . dropWhile (not . isDigit)` for "standard" throwing version).

Comment: One could also imagine doing `getNumber = asum . map readMaybe . words`, depending on the specifications of the format.

Comment: Why require an older external package to get `readMay`? Just use `Text.Read.readMaybe` from the base library.