# How to transform a String into a list of tuple?

Tags: haskell

We have a String that if shown with putStr would produce the timetable for buses.

it looks something like this:
    "4 | 12 32 52\n5 | 12 32 52\n"

What I need to work with is to change it into this form:
    [{4, [12 32 52]},{5, [12 32 52]}] 
I need int to work with.

Please don't solve it, just give me ideas, or functions that might help.

Also we were told to use groupBy, but for group and groupBy I only get a "not in scope"

Comment: Both `group` and `groupBy` reside in Data.List module which you would need to add to your import list. You can use [Hoogle](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=groupBy) to search functions by their name or type signature and identify in which module they are.
You may also find [unlines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) useful for splitting the string into individual lines, and the `readMany` function from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176706/reading-ints-in-haskell/20177526#20177526) for extracting Ints from your string.

Comment: In haskell, your list of tuple should be in this form  [(4, [12, 32, 52]), (5, [12, 32, 52])]

Answer (score 0):

Daniel!

Yeah, you could use groupBy for helping you.

Here's the doc: 
[hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy)

And here are two nice examples:

[example1](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/groupBy_f.html)

[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316365/haskell-surprising-behavior-of-groupby)

So, you gotta decide what's in your function (a -> a -> Bool) for grouping the way you want. 
Also, you have to decide if you need just one group criterion or more than one. 
We could say, you have this pattern "a | b\na | b\n", and so on, well, you need to decide where "to cut" for grouping but also what happens with "a" and "b".

And that's it.

I hope I could help.